# Can't define transform: scale(); in CSS using event-listeners (js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

So I want to define the opacity of this div element to 0 using CSS, and then toggle it using JS event listener. Here is my code: 
HTML:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", clicked);
});

function clicked(){
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  div.classList.toggle("divDisplay");
}
```

```css
div{
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: transform 1s;
}

.divDisplay{
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
<div>Some text...</div>
```

Here is a link to my real code, there is my real problem:
https://codepen.io/mattanelkaim/pen/wvMrreW

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I am not getting this. What is the issue here?

Comment: When I click the button, the div won't toggle the class divDisplay.

Comment: @str What do you mean?

Comment: @mattanelium I mean, I cannot reproduce the problem that you mention. Click "Run code snippet" in your question and see for yourself; it works.

Comment: @str OK, now I changed it to transform: scale(); and it won't work!

Comment: `transform: (1);` is not valid CSS. Do you mean `transform: scale(1);`? But that won't animate as you did not tell it to (only `opacity` animates). Please try to provide an actual [mcve] from the beginning.

Comment: Your code is working fine with `transition: all 1s;`

Comment: @str Sorry, my mistake. I fixed it and now it is working. I gave an example of my problem (in my real code). I did it because I can't put all my code in this website. Do you know any website that allows me to upload my real code (as text), I will send you a link and you will have a look at my real problem?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please wait a few minutes. I will upload my code to codepen, and I will send you a link to my full code.

Comment: OK, so here is the link: https://codepen.io/mattanelkaim/pen/wvMrreW.
As you can see, I tried to toggle the transform: scale(); of ".img-opened". Can you please help me? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Can someone please help me?? str??

Comment: There are multiple problems: Error message in the console, CSS specifity issue, and the fact that you are trying to animate from `scale(0)` to `scale(0)`. But as has been described in the link I posted earlier, please do not just add a link off-site with a pile of code but provide a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: How can I fix the error message in the console?

Comment: And what do you mean by "CSS specifity issue"?

Answer (score 0):

you can try in css putting div{opacity:0 !important;}
The !important overwrites any attribute you had before for the element

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work. This is not about overwriting...